# производная n-го порядка на питоне

Tags: python, математика

нужно написать код, который считает производную n-го порядка от функции 1/(1+x^3). так как там нет общей формулы, не понятно как задать производную. может быть как-то рекуррентно?
к чему я пришла:

```
def derivative (x, order):
 if (order == 0):
        return func(x)
 else:
       return  (-order)*(1+x**3)**(-order-1)*(3*x**2)*(order)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Вы можете использовать таблицу производных как шаблон. После чего по ней составлять свое выражение

Comment: Если все же, Ваша цель получить производную, а не написать самостоятельную функцию, то рекомендую использовать sympy.diff

Answer (score 0):

Для вычисления производной n-го порядка функции 1/(1+x^3), можно воспользоваться методом символьного дифференцирования с использованием библиотеки символьной математики, такой как SymPy. SymPy позволяет вычислять производные функций символьно.

Вот пример того, как это можно сделать с использованием SymPy:

```py
import sympy as sp

# Создайте символьную переменную
x = sp.symbols('x')

# Определите функцию
func = 1 / (1 + x**3)

# Вычислите n-ую производную
n = 3  # Замените на необходимое значение n
derivative = sp.diff(func, x, n)

# Выведите результат
print(derivative)
```

В этом примере мы создаем символьную переменную `x`, определяем функцию `func`, а затем используем `sp.diff` для вычисления n-ой производной от `func`. В результате получаем символьное выражение для производной.

Замените значение `n` на то, которое вам нужно, чтобы получить n-ую производную. SymPy автоматически выполнит символьное дифференцирование и вернет символьное выражение для производной.